# It makes no sense why "Specified cast is not valid." in this case. Or does it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I can't figure out why the server is experiencing an error and drawing attention to the `foreach` loop in the following piece of code

```
using Microsoft.CSharp;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.IO;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;
using AllyPortal.Models;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace AllyPortal.Controllers
{
    public class AssetBundleController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index(string bguid)
        {
            // bguid: bundle guid, the guid corresponding to one or more assets in the table 

            PortalData PD = new PortalData();

            ViewBag.inputtedGuid = bguid;

            ViewBag.checkedAssetLinks = new List<string> ();

            foreach (AssetLink thislink in PD.links)
            {

                if (thislink.linkguid.Equals(bguid, StringComparison.Ordinal))
                {
                    AssetFile thisAssetFile = PD.files.FirstOrDefault(f => f.fileid == thislink.fileid);
                    ViewBag.links.Add("../../Assets/" + PD.getFullFileName(thisAssetFile));
                }

            }

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

For reference, the model in question is

```
[Table( Name = "links")]
public class AssetLink
{
    public AssetLink()
    {

    }

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int linkid { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string linkguid { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public int fileid { get; set; }

}
```

inside

```
public class PortalData : DataContext
{
     ...
}
```

There is another class

```
[Table( Name = "files" )]
public class AssetFile
{
    public AssetFile()
    {

    }

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
    public int fileid { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public int orgid { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public int catid { get; set; }
    [Column]
    public string filename { get; set; }

}
```

which I've used to iterate through with

```
foreach (AssetFile f in PD.files)
{

       ....
}
```

in another controller, so what's different about this one that could be causing the error? Let me know if I need to post any more code to give you a point of reference.

Yellow screen of death:

> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not
>   valid.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 26:             ViewBag.assetLinks = new List (); Line
>   27:              Line 28:             foreach (AssetLink thislink in
>   PD.links) Line 29:             { Line 30:
>
> Source File: c:\Users\me\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2013\Projects\someproj\someproj\Controllers\AssetBundleController.cs
>   Line: 28
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32() +5317537
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetInt32(Int32 i) +62

Comment: whats the error? where is it happening? you need to provide more specific info on what the actual issue is.

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: I said it's the `foreach` loop, `foreach (AssetLink thislink in PD.links)`. I'll paste the yellow screen of death for you guys.

Comment: You have redacted a critical piece of the puzzle - the declaration of `PortalData.links`.  What is the type of that property?

Comment: Either you have multiple `AssetLink` classes or `PD.links` isn't an enumeration of `AssetLink`?

Comment: Please add the definition of `links` property in `PortalData` class.

Comment: @DStanley The type of that is `Table<AssetLink>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the stack trace, the error occurs here:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBuffer.get_Int32() +5317537
```

while trying to enumerate `PD.links`.  That seems to indicate that you are getting a different type from the source for one of your `int` properties.  Check the data types of `linkid` and `fileid` in the `links` table and make sure they are both integer types.

Answer (score 1):

the code

```
foreach (AssetLink thislink in PD.links)
```

Performs a cast of the `thisLink` object for each iteration. Check the type of `PD.Links` - an `IEnumerable` can return *any* `object` and an `IEnumerable<T>` will return anything of type `T`, which may be more derived than `AssetLink` and thus contain something that isn't an `AssetLink`.

If you want to *filter* to the given type, rather than expect *all* values to match, try changing to

```
using System.Linq;
//...
foreach(var thisLink in PD.Links.OfType<AssetLink>())
```

As this will only return objects which are already `AssetLink`s and skip everything else.